# Live webcam stream --> server --> remote viewers

Tags: video-streaming

My goal is to stream from a webcam to a server and then to users. The webcam will have a very slow upload speed, and I only want that stream to be uploaded once to a remote server on a fatter connection which then streams to the end user..

There are external steaming sites like ustream, but I'm looking for a solution that can be hosted on a standard linux server, with no outside providers required.

It doesn't appear like QuickTime or Flash really have a mechanism for this, although QuickTime does have a nice client/server bundle if the client is a Mac.

Comment: If you don't want to pay for products such as Flash Media Server or Wowza Media Server, then maybe you can look at Red5: http://red5.org/

Answer (score 2):

The Flash eco-system is certaily one way to go. Flash Media Encoder is free, for server you can use Red5 and the client is the flash player.

HTML5 is an other way. If you feel adventurous you can check out my new, WebM-based livestreaming server, [stream.m](http://code.google.com/p/stream-m/). It is an early release but you can check it out if it suits your needs.

You can produce WebM stream on your home computer using **ffmpeg**, send it to the server running **stream.m**, then it distrivutes to any HTML5-compatible **browser**. Safari and IE has no native WebM support, but Google has a [free plugin](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/webmmf) to play it.